# JqueryMobile listview Scrollbar is not displaying in Phonegap

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova, jquery-mobile-listview

I am developing an android application using JqueryMobile with Phonegap.  I created a page containing an unordered list.

```
<div id='pg_remote-address-book' data-role="page"> 
  <div data-role="content" id="pg_remote-address-book_content" data-scroll="true">
    <ul data-role="listview" id="ul_address_list">
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am loading the listitems dynamically (like lazy loading) inside the unordered list using AJAX.

While testing in the android device, I was expecting by default a scrollbar will come in the list view.  But it is not coming.  Is there anything missing?

Comment: scroll bars will show on when page scrolls only, if you firebug content div, you will see that it has `overflow-y: visible` if that property was set to `scroll` instead, scroll bars will appear on content div.

Comment: @Omar - I check with firebug.  Found that `.ui-content{overflow-y:visible}`  I tried override in my custom css as `overflow-y: scroll !important`.  But still the same.

Comment: when using `oveflow-y: scroll`, you need to set a fixed `height`.

Comment: @Omar - Since I am developing for mobile devices the height is dynamic right.  Any idea on that?

Comment: Definitely, it's dynamic. But if you still want to show scroll bars on listview, then you can set `height: 50%` or `max-height` and `overflow-y: scroll`. I'm not a CSS guru honestly ;)